# MariaDB SQL query returns truncated numbers from select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, truncate

I am trying to pull data from Maria DB. The datatype in schema is DECIMAL (12, 8).
In my program when I query using following query. it trucates to 4 (or 3) decimal places and also round off.

```
select CAST(FORMAT(latitude, 100) AS FLOAT) latitude from mytable
```

it returns 36.173 . In DB it is stored as 36.17298200
I want it to return as 36.172982

Comment: Which type field is latitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official MySQL documents:

> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data. In MySQL, NUMERIC is implemented as DECIMAL, so the following remarks about DECIMAL apply equally to NUMERIC.

[Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value) - FLOAT, DOUBLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

So you should be writing something similar to:

```
select CAST(FORMAT(latitude, 100) AS DECIMAL(8,6)) latitude from mytable
```

As 8 is the total number of digits and 6 is precision.

Comment: I get following error with above change           >       raise errorclass(errno, errval)
E       pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(8, 6)) latitude from schemaName.tableName' at line 1").

Comment: My bad, remove the space after `,` in `(8, 6)` and convert it to `(8,6)`

Comment: Change `FLOAT` to `DECIMAL` and it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

To use the number in calculations, simply use it.  No conversion, no `CAST`.

To *dislay* it to 6 decimal places, do that on `SELECTing`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(latitude, 6) ...
```

`FORMAT(..., 100)` should give you lots of decimal places.

`FLOAT` does not have enough precision to distinguish more than 6 or 7 *significant* decimal places.  That is, the first and third numbers nere are the closest representable numbers in `FLOAT`:

```
x4210b122 --> 36.172981262207
              36.17298200
x4210b123 --> 36.172985076904
```

Double:

```
x40421624463065f9 --> 36.1729819999999975
```

For Latitude and Longitude:

```
FLOAT  has a resolution of 1.7 m or 5.6 ft -- good enough for Vehicles
DECIMAL(8,6)               16 cm    1/2 ft -- Friends in a mall
```